# scanning pixels of .tiff image using imageJ library

Tags: java, getpixel, imagej

im using the imageJ library to read a .tiff image file. But when im trying to read the pixels of image1 in variable c, i get an error saying "incompatible types: required int, found int[].
im quiet new to java, so can somebody tell me how to get around this problem. The code is otherwise working fine with other image formats.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import ij.ImagePlus;

public class GetPixelCoordinates {

//int y, x, tofind, col;
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws IOException  
 */
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        try {
            //read image file

            ImagePlus img = new ImagePlus("E:\\abc.tiff");

            //write file
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("E:\\log.txt");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

            //find cyan pixels
            for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {

                    int c = img.getPixel(x,y);
                    Color color = new Color(c);


                     if (color.getRed() < 30 && color.getGreen() >= 225 && color.getBlue() >= 225) {
                         out.write("CyanPixel found at=" + x + "," + y);
                         out.newLine();

                     }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for `getPixel(int,int)` in `ImagePlus`](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/ImagePlus.html#getPixel%28int,%20int%29) you'll see that it returns an array of `int`s rather than a single `int`:

> Returns the pixel value at (x,y) as a 4 element array. Grayscale values are retuned in the first element. RGB values are returned in the first 3 elements. For indexed color images, the RGB values are returned in the first 3 three elements and the index (0-255) is returned in the last.

It looks as if you're dealing with an RGB image, so you should be able to do the following instead:

```
int [] colorArray = image1.getPixel(x,y);

int redValue = colorArray[0];
int greenValue = colorArray[1];
int blueValue = colorArray[2];
```